# Dependency not detected when switching environments in angular

Tags: angular

I am working on a project that i cloned from github. i added a new environment called Live . But when i try to serve my project on that configuration using this command : ng serve --configuration=liev it apparently doesn't detect primeng dependencies. But on the other hand it works fine with ng serve only .

[This is the Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7rAFP.png)

[This is the env configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WAEQ1.png)

[This is the live configuration that i added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e01vJ.png)

[This is the serve Part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s6h6Y.png)

I tried to make some changes inside the configuration parameters in live but it's not working!

My goal is to serve it using ng serve --configuration:live

Comment: In the angular.json, u should add a "live" section also under "architect" param.